NP-hardness of solving systems of *homogeneous* polynomial equations
It is well-known that deciding if a system of quadratic polynomial equations in several variables admits a solution in a finite field is NP-complete. There is a simple reduction from 3SAT, that works modulo 2.
Take a clause, say $C = \overline{x} \vee y \vee z$. Introduce a new variable $t$ and consider the two polynomial equations $(1 + x) + y + (1+x)y + t = 0$ and $t + z + tz + 1 = 0$. Any assignement of $x,y,z,t$ that satisfies the two quadratic polynomial equation also satisfies the original clause (and vice-versa).
The thing is that this reduction yields inhomogeneous polynomials (i.e. containing both quadratic and linear terms).
My question is: how to prove that deciding the existence of a non-zero solution to a system of homogeneous polynomial equations in degree at most 2 is NP-hard?

After thinking harder, I found a solution.
EDIT: this was in fact readily available, in a slightly different form, in the published literature. P. Koiran. The complexity of local dimensions for constructible sets. J. Complexity, 16(1):311–323, 2000.
Introduce a new variable $h$ and add the polynomial equation $h x_i = x_i^2$ for each other variable $x_i$. If $x_i \neq 0$, then necessarily $x_i = h$ (and therefore $h \neq 0)$. Therefore any non-zero solution of these equations has $h \neq 0$.
Deal with negation as follows. For each negative literal $\neg x_i$, introduce a new variable $y_i$ and add the equation $y_i^2 = (x_i - h)^2 = x_i^2 - 2 h x_i + h^2$.
Given a 3-clause (say) $x_i \lor \neg x_j \lor x_k$, introduce a new variable $t$ and translate it by writing the two polynomial $x_i^2 + y_j^2 - x_iy_j = t^2$ and $t^2 + x_k^2 - tx_k = h^2$.
This yields a homogeneous polynomial system composed entirely of quadratic polynomials. If the input 3SAT instance admits a satisfying truth assignment, then the polynomial system is satisfied by $h=1$ and these 0/1 values for $x_1, \dots, x_n$. If the polynomial system has a non-zero solution, then dividing all variables by the value of $h$ in this solution yields another solution where $h=1$ and the $x_i$ are 0/1 variables. It is easy to check that these satisfy the clauses.

Hi @CharlesBouillaguet! You may be interested by this paper of mine. We give a reduction (Lemma 1, due to an older paper of Koiran) from Boolsys whose input is a system boolean equations of the form $x_i= true$, $x_i=¬x_j$ or $x_i=x_j\vee x_k$. You might be interested by variants of this result, in particular about square homogeneous systems with as many equations as variables.

Hi @Bruno! Long time no see :-). Thanks for the pointer, I will look into it.

Very nice solution!  Thank you for explaining this to me so patiently.
